# How to access SVN in Python?

Tags: python, svn

I was trying to implement an extension to an exception collecting system.

After extracting file path and line number from an exception, I want to know who wrote that line and one obvious to accomplish this is "svn blame".

But I don't know how to access SVN in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are bindings for `subversion` [here](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html) called `pysvn`. I've never used them, but they seem reasonable.

You can also just use the `subprocess` module and call out to `svn`, but I'd try the bindings first.

Comment: +1 I actually created my own hg python binding, although there exist the mercurial (internal api and highly unstable), and hgapi out there. All I did was Popen so there is flexibility. Depends.

Comment: I've used PySVN for quick scripts and full applications. It can be a little inconsistent, but I've found it to be very, very useful.

Comment: @User007 ugh don't get me started on hg's bindings.

Comment: @detly Is it possible to do `svn blame` with PySVN? I can't find a blame function in a Client object.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic It's [here](http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_annotate).